# How do I receive the whole Tweet in Tweepy Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tweepy

I have created a streaming program in Python to receive Tweets, however I notice it only returns part of the text of the tweet. I have looked at similar problems, and know I must insert 'tweet_mode="extended"' somewhere, and have inserted it into Stream, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_secret)

class MyListener(StreamListener):
    def on_data(self, data):
        with open(file_name, "a") as file:
            tweetDict = {"text": "", "coordinates": ""}
            tweet = json.loads(data)
            json.dump(tweet, file, indent=4)
            file.write("\n")
            return True

twitter_stream = Stream(auth, MyListener(), tweet_mode="extended")
twitter_stream.filter(track=[target])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The full tweet is in the json response.

You can find it under:

```
tweet = json.loads(data)
tweet["retweeted_status"]["extended_tweet"]["full_text"]
```

Comment: This works fine, however I'll add a try/except as tweets that aren't extended cause a read error.